# Schema.org - Correct way to set up a football (soccer) club with multiple teams

Tags: schema.org

I have a football club - **Deal Community Sports FC**, which has two teams - *First Team* and *Reserves*.

I began implementing the **sportsTeam** markup from schema.org for **Deal Community Sports**, but then ran into a brick wall of confusion when it came to including the two teams as a part of the club as a whole.

Should I be marking up Deal Community Sports as an **organization** or **sportsClub** and then including the two teams as **members**, or is there another more suitable way to do it? Ideally I don't want to have the club and each team as entirely separate entities, as this does not seem right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the whole club, you could use one of these types (whichever matches according to your understanding of how the club works): [`SportsOrganization`](http://schema.org/SportsOrganization) or the more specific [`SportsTeam`](http://schema.org/SportsTeam).

For each team, use [`SportsTeam`](http://schema.org/SportsTeam).

And to relate these entities, you could use one of these properties (whichever is appropriate according to your understanding of the club):

- [`department`](http://schema.org/department)
- [`member`](http://schema.org/member)
- [`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization)

Comment: Clear and concise answer. Thanks unor.

Comment: this answer was useful [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13297/1511). thanks!